# How to open a new page once the user gives the permission?

Tags: java, android

In my signup page I ask the user to give the permission to access location in order to continue but once i give permission instead of taking me to main page it stays in  signup page(Note that the permission is given and when i create a new account it works normally) .I want to directly enter the main page once the user gives the permissions
This is my code

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding=ActivitySignUpBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        spinner=findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Options, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        progressdialog=new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
        progressdialog.setTitle("Creating Account");
        progressdialog.setMessage("please wait while we create your account");
        binding.SignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressdialog.show();
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(binding.Email.getText().toString()
                        ,binding.Password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        progressdialog.dismiss();
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && !binding.Username.getText().toString().equals("") ) {
                            ActionCodeSettings actionCodeSettings =
                                    ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
                                            // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
                                            // URL must be whitelisted in the Firebase Console.
                                            .setUrl("https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234")
                                            // This must be true
                                            .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
                                            .setIOSBundleId("com.example.ios")
                                            .setAndroidPackageName(
                                                    "com.example.android",
                                                    true, /* installIfNotAvailable */
                                                    "12"    /* minimumVersion */)
                                            .build();
                            String email = binding.Email.getText().toString();
                            FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                            auth.sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, actionCodeSettings)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                Log.d("TAG", "Email sent.");
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                            Users user = new Users(binding.Username.getText().toString(), binding.Email.getText().toString(),binding.Call.getText().toString());
                            String id = task.getResult().getUser().getUid();
                            String selectedOption = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                            database.getReference().child("Users").child(selectedOption).child(id).setValue(user);
                            boolean Loccheck = checkLocationPermission();
                            if (Loccheck) {
                                Intent intent;
                                if (selectedOption.contains("Delivery")) {
                                    intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, DriversMapsActivity.class);
                                } else {
                                    intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, Custhomepage.class);
                                }
                                startActivity(intent);

                            }
                        }
                            else { //if there is error in signup
                                if (binding.Username.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, "Please enter a username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(SignUp.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        }



                });//to check if value match
            }
        });

    }





    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String text=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }//Ignore this

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }//Ignore this
    public boolean checkLocationPermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Should we show an explanation?
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                // Show an explanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(title_location_permission)
                        .setMessage(R.string.text_location_permission)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(SignUp.this,
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
                            }
                        })
                        .create()
                        .show();


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }//PROBLEM IS HERE
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After granting the permission

Use `onRequestPermissionsResult` from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#java)

Code:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
            if (grantResults.length > 0 &&
                    grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow
                // in your app.
            }  else {
                // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because
                // the features requires a permission that the user has denied.
                // At the same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to
                // system settings in an effort to convince the user to change
                // their decision.
            }
            return;
        }
        // Other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request.
    }
}
```

Comment: Heyy can u tell me where exactly in my code should I put this code ?

Comment: when you call `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);` and after user reject/granted permission it will redirect into `onRequestPermissionsResult` so you can call new intent on succes case.